# node-ipc error "Messages are large, You may want to consider smaller messages."

Tags: node.js, unix-socket, node-ipc

So I am trying to setup a socket server in node.js using node-ipc, then send data from a client. I can connect perfectly fine, however when I send data I recieve the error `Messages are large, You may want to consider smaller messages.` I have followed all advice [here](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/issues/79), however, have still been unsuccessful in resolving the problem. I have tried sending from a socket connection in C and also from terminal. Any advice would be great, thanks in advance.

main.js

````js
const ipc = require("node-ipc");
const socket = '/tmp/edufuse.sock';
ipc.serve(
    socket,
    function(){
      ipc.server.on(
          'myEvent',
          function(data){
            ipc.log('got a message : '.debug, data);
          }
      );
    }
);
ipc.server.start();

test.json
```json
{ type: message, data: { foo: bar } }
````

command from terminal

```sh
pr -tF test.json | nc -U /tmp/edufuse.sock
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears this is an underlying problem with node-ipc. In order to get around this, I used net sockets and TCP.

```
const net = require('net');
const port = 8080;
const host = '127.0.0.1';

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data){
    let str = data.toString('utf8');
    console.log(str);
    try {
      let json = JSON.parse(str);
      console.log(json);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error str: ' + str);
    }

  });
  socket.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
});

server.listen(port, host);
```